# How do i pull all data columns from multiple tables that each have different number of columns?

Tags: sql, join

Im trying to pull all data from multiple tables using:

```
USE [DBNAME]
GO
SELECT *
    FROM FOOD AS f
    JOIN DESSERT AS d ON f.DESSERT_KEY = d.DESSERT_KEY
    JOIN SNACK AS s ON d.SNACK_KEY = s.SNACK_KEY
    JOIN SAMPLES AS smpl ON s.SAMPLES_KEY = smpl.SAMPLES_KEY
WHERE FOOD_ID = 'Order1'
GO
```

The tables names are random for ambiguity. The tables have a different number of columns each with some of the same data columns and some different. I have tried joining the tables with their keys and want to pass in a food ID that pulls all the data related to this ID. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: This doesn't look like MySQL code.  Are you sure you tagged the question correctly?

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: hi sorry i mistagged it. I am using sql on microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: The problem with my query is that it is pulling alot of data and some duplicate tables. I want to know how to make a query that pulls all the columns of each table and puts them in their own rows without having many duplicates

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Is there an error here? What are you trying to get to?  (See jarlh's link above as a good starting point).

Answer (score 0):

you need to specifie the table where the `FOOD_ID` is coming from but let me assume that it is coming from `FOOD` table

```
USE [DBNAME]
GO
SELECT *
    FROM FOOD AS f
    JOIN DESSERT AS d ON f.DESSERT_KEY = d.DESSERT_KEY
    JOIN SNACK AS s ON d.SNACK_KEY = s.SNACK_KEY
    JOIN SAMPLES AS smpl ON s.SAMPLES_KEY = smpl.SAMPLES_KEY
WHERE f.FOOD_ID = 'Order1'
GO
```